# Difficulty importing Selenium tests into Katalon - Illegal string body character after dollar sign

Tags: selenium, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm trying to import Selenium tests into Katalon and I keep getting this error - am I not escaping dollar sign correctly?

```
try { if (selenium.getText("//div[@id='footer']/p[@class='copyright']").matches("^\\$\\{sbxFooter1\\}[\\s\\S]*$")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what the exact error message is

Comment: Try using single quotes around your `matches` string instead of double quotes

Comment: @tim_yates Can you be more specific? Here's what I tried below without success 

for (int second = 0;; second++) {
 if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
 try { if (selenium.getText('//div[@id='footer']/p[@class='copyright']').matches('^\\$\\{sbxFooter1\\}[\\s\\S]*$")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
 Thread.sleep(1000);
}

Comment: @Thomas the specific message is "illegal string body character after dollar sign" and then says to escape a literal dollar sign with either a backslash or brackets. I've tried everything with no luck. New to Katalon so I really, really appreciate it

Comment: I think tim_yates is right regarding single quotes. Alternatively you might take a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363786/5956451

Comment: @Thomas Single quotes don't seem to work. Any chance you can provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

In Java regex the following symbols need to be escaped:

```
\.[]{}()*+-?^$|
```

If your regular expression is

```
^${sbxFooter}[\s\S]*$
```

you could try

`\^\$\{sbxFooter\}\[\\s\\S\]\*` inside double or single quotes